# How to refresh IP address using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm using a rotating proxy that changes the IP for every request. However, it seems I have to recreate the webdriver instance every time it order for the browser to "register" the IP address. Is there a way to update the webdriver IP without reinstantiating everytime?

```
options = {
            'proxy': {
                'http': 'http://{proxy_host}:{proxy_port}',
                'https': 'http://{proxy_host}:{proxy_port}',
                'verify_ssl': False,
            },
            'options': {
                'headless': True,
                'user_agent': self.get_new_user_agent(),
                'experimental': {
                    'prefs': {
                        'profile.managed_default_content_settings.images': 2,
                        'profile.managed_default_content_settings.stylesheets': 2,
                        'profile.managed_default_content_settings.plugins': 2,
                        'profile.managed_default_content_settings.media_stream': 2,
                        'profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications': 2,
                        'profile.default_content_setting_values.xhrBlocked': 2,
                        'profile.managed_default_content_settings.geolocation': 2,
                    },
                    'arguments': [
                        '--user-data-dir=D:/My Documents'
                    ]
                }
            }
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(seleniumwire_options=options)
self.driver.get('http://whatismyip.com')
```